# Layer package duplication

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I create a layer package from desktop 10 and the double click to decompress it on my machine (to see what the customer is going to see).
I get the initial folder (same as my lpk file) and then another one duplicated inside.  c:\documents and settings\users\myusername\My Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\mylpkfile2-17-11\mylpkfile2-17-11
There are data files in both folder structures (with shape files in both).
There is a lyr file in the root folder that points to the first dataset.
I see a lyr for v10 in the v10 folder.
However this lyr uses the same data as the other lyr.
[image: Layer structure]

It looks to me that there is no reason for this data structure.
I don't know if it is just my machine or ...   Does anyone else see this also?

The above occurs if I double click on the lpk. If I run the extract package tool from within arcmap it extracts only one folder structure to the location I instruct it to.

Comment: Try and consolidate the layer - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Consolidate_Layer/0017000000q2000000/

Comment: That's not really what I want to do. Each shape file in my mxd is a different classification. Just found out that the output folder can't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

By default, layer packaging creates v10 and v9.3.1 layers (and data if necessary depending on the GDB version).  I think you are just seeing both here.  If you do not want this behavior, use the layer packaging GP tool to just package v10 layers.

Comment: no gdb invlolved. All shape files. It has something to do with the double click event. just wondering if it is just my machine or if it is reproducable.